# Creating multiple tables with Symfony & Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

Starting my first Symfony/doctrine project I created 2 entities (user & property) using:

```
$php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

This works fine and gives me the two needed php files with the classes and annotions.

After this I want to create the corresponding tables in my database using:

```
$php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Only the first table (user) is created.  What's going wrong?  What do i have to do to have both tables created.  BTW: no error message received...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

before

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: Sorry, this makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! There was a syntax error in the property class.  But doctrine:schema:update did not give any error... :-(

When trying doctrine:schema:create I got the error message.  Corrected it and afterwards doctrine:schema:update worked well!

Answer (score 0):

always backing up your entities before you update schema ..

for backing up entities write

```
>php app/console doctrine:generate:entities projectname
```

If there is Error In entity It will show you.